# CSS DJANGO and extended templates

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

I've loaded bootstrap into my base.html template which extends all my other templates

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/portal.css' %}" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css' %}" />
<html>
    <title>
    {% block title %}Test Portal{% endblock %}
    </title>
    <head>
        <div class="page-header">
            <img src="{% static 'images/gd_logo_lg.jpg' %}" alt="GDLOGO" style="width:245;height:125px;"/>
            <div id="righty">
                <h1><a href="/home/">GD Portal</a></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
            </head>

    <body>
    <div class="content container">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
    </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

only some CSS works from my CSS file, `css/portal.css`, I've tried looking online but everything I've tried doesn't work.

```
.page-header {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #932D42;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 10px 40px 20px 40px;
}

.page-header img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}

.righty {
    float:right:
}

.page-header h1, .page-header h1 a, .page-header h1 a:visited, .page-header h1 a:active {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 32pt;
    font-family: "Courier New", monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;


h1, h2, h3, h4 {
    font-family: 'Impact', Sans-serif;
}
```

for instance, page-header works fine I can change that and do what I want, but righty doesn't have any affect what so ever.
Any CSS I try in my extended templates also doesn't work.

Could someone explain what I've done wrong because I feel like I'm missing something super basic?

Comment: Tried my updated answer yet.?

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi yes, it worked and it was a combination of wrong class/id calls and also I missing the `}` from the bottom of one of the `.page-header` ones before that. so that also didn't help

Comment: I am glad that you found the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand how to select an element by id or by class.
In your html file  :

```
<div id="righty">
    <h1><a href="/home/">GD Portal</a></h1>
</div>
```

But your css has this code :

```
.righty {
    float:right;
}
```

"div" has the **id** attribute as righty.So in css,the exact code should be :

```
<style>
 #righty {
     float:right;
 } 

</style>
```

For **id** the css and Javascript element selector is **#** and for class, it is simple dot ( . ).

If still not working,use this code :

```
<style>
 .righty {
     text-align: right !important;
 } 

</style>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, I've also tried `<div class="righty"> with a dot and still nothing.

Comment: The `:` should be a semi-colon too

Comment: @Jim Updated my answer as the Sayse suggested.Check now.